# beanstalkd default wal directory

Tags: php, macos, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

We are using Laravel with BeansTalkD for queuing in our app. Now I am stuck at a point that this command :

`php artisan queue:listen`

keeps getting jobs, in other words there are a lot of jobs and I have no idea how to clean the queue.

And the problem is that I ran the beanstalkd using this command:

`beanstalkd -z 1024*1024`

which does not specify `wal` directory.

I have been searching for the whole last week on how to clean beanstalk work queue, but found nothing.

**Tips**

- I am running this on Mac OS X Yosemite.
- Restarting BeansTalkD service did not solve it
- I don't store jobs in DB so flush command is not the one. (I don't know if Laravel does that with me knowing but I don't think so)
- I am deleting the jobs when I am done but the app generates a lot of jobs.

Comment: You mean the jobs are not processed?

Comment: How does `-z` and WAL directory connected? `-z` sets the max job size in bytes, `-b` on the other hand allows you specify WAL directory.

Comment: Do you just want to delete all the jobs from the queue (tube)? Or something else?

Comment: @peterm I did not say they are connected, the point is that I ran the command without specifying the -b option

Comment: @peterm I just want to delete everything in the queue

Comment: @Bogdan no the jobs are processed, what I want is just deleting the current jobs from the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't use `-b` option then restarting `beanstalkd` (again without `-b`) should help.

Now if restarting for some reason doesn't work for you and you're using Laravel 5.x you can consider installing [artisan-beans](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/artisan-beans) package and use `php artisan beans:purge` command to clean up your queue.

---

**UPDATE:** Since you're on Laravel 4.2 you can

1. install dependency-free CLI tool [beanstool](https://github.com/src-d/beanstool). Here's how install v2.0 on OS X

   ```
   wget https://github.com/tyba/beanstool/releases/download/v0.2.0/beanstool_v0.2.0_darwin_amd64.tar.gz
   tar -xvzf beanstool_v0.2.0_darwin_amd64.tar.gz
   cp beanstool_v0.2.0_darwin_amd64/beanstool /usr/local/bin/
   ```
2. and then run this in `bash`

   ```
   for i in {1..N}; do beanstool delete -t default --state=ready; done
   ```

   *Change `N` to the number of jobs you want to delete at once and `default` to the name of your queue (tube).*

   If you wonder how many jobs you currently have in the queue run

   ```
   beanstool stats
   ```

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2

Comment: I found another solution check it out in the answer below :) thx alot man

Answer (score 0):

Beside the accepted answer I found another solution which is to stop (CTRL+C) the command:

`beanstalkd -z 1048576`

and start a the command again with the `-b` option:

`beanstalkd -z 1048576 -b ~/btd_data`

this also solved the problem